# How to optimize Workqueue of well know time consuming processes

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have an IEnumerable of actions and they are decendent ordered by the time they will consume when executing. Now i want all of them to be executed in parallel. Are there any better solutions than this one?

```
IEnumerable<WorkItem> workItemsOrderedByTime = myFactory.WorkItems.DecendentOrderedBy(t => t.ExecutionTime);
Parallel.ForEach(workItemsOrderedByTime, t => t.Execute(), Environment.ProcessorCount);
```

So my idea is to first execute all expensice tasks in terms of time they need to be done.

EDIT: The question is if there is a better solution to get all done in minimum of time.

Comment: Why do you want to first execute all expensive tasks?

Comment: Because so i can guarantee that all long running tasks are executed first and in sum the whole execution of all tasks is optimized. Because otherwise it can happen that 9 of 10 tasks are finished and the last one is executed on 1 core and all other cores are doing nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve your [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of

> Because otherwise it can happen that 9 of 10 tasks are finished and the last one is executed on 1 core and all other cores are doing nothing.

What you need to do is tell `Parallel.ForEach` to only take one item from the source list at a time. That way when you are down to the last items you won't have a bunch of slow work items all in a single core's queue.

This can be done by using [`Partitioner.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136328(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing in [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(workItems, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering), 
                new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount},
                t => t.Execute());
```

Comment: Are all workItems executed in parallel within that solution? I do not understand the difference between the default partitioner. Lets asume there are workItems ordered like that. <6, 5, 4, 3, 2 1> and we have 2 cores. What i want is that core 1 executes 6 and core 2 executes 5. When 5 or 6 is finished 4 is done and so on. What would be the order of execution with the default partitioner?

Comment: The default partitioner may grab items 6,5 and give them to the queue for core 1, then grab 4,3 and give it to core two. There is a overhead cost to enumerating the IEnumerable in a thread safe way so the partitioner likes to batch out the items it takes. By turning off that batching you get the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

1. By default there is no execution order guarantee in `Parallel.ForEach`
2. That is why your call to `DecendentOrderedBy` does not do anything good. Though it might do something bad: in case default partitioner decides to do a *range* partition dividing say 12 `WorkItems` into 4 groups of 3 items, by the order in `IEnumerable`. Then first core has much more work to do, thus creating the problem you try to avoid.
3. Easy fix to (2) is explained in the answer by [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain). If `Parallel.ForEach` takes just one item then you naturally get some load balancing. In most cases this will work fine
4. The optimal (in most cases) solution for an ordered `IEnumerable` (as you have) will be [Striped Partitioning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/05/28/partitioning-in-plinq/) number of buckets = number of cores. AFIK there you don't get this out-of-the-box in .NET. But you can provide a custom [OrderablePartitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394988(v=vs.110).aspx) that will partition data just this way.

I am sorry to say it but: "No free lunch"